# How Do I Change "Open In" Destination In iOS

Tags: ios

My app works with the "open in" feature, but the file is sent to App/Documents/Inbox. I need the file to be sent to App/Documents, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is standard behavior that a file sent to your app is put in the Inbox folder.

All you need to do is move it to where you want or delete it when you are done with it.

Use `NSFileManager` to move the file or delete it as needed.

Comment: Im sorry if this sounds dumb, but how would i use NSFileManager? (i just need the files to go to the App/Documents because the files don't show up if they are in App/Documents/inbox)

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `NSFileManager`? There are methods for moving files.

Comment: i found it now, it was under frameworks, but i do not know how i use it.

Comment: Remember, the best skill a programmer can have is to be able to search. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nsfilemanager+move+file

Comment: You're welcome. As a reminder (since you are new here), if you find an answer helpful you can up vote it. If it answers your question, you can accept it (click on the checkmark next to the answer). This tells people the question is closed.